# Splitting Y-axis in bar plot - R

Tags: r, bar-chart

How can i split my y-axis in bar plot while plotting in R.

Sample data:

```
   Name     Freq
  PRIM2      310
 NBPF20       45
  NBPF1       12
   CD24       11
 SEC22B        7
 ZNF718        7
```

The code I am using to plot this:

```
d <- read.table("Sample.txt", header=TRUE)
barplot(d$Freq, names.arg=d$Name, col='red', cex.axis=0.8, cex.names=0.7, las=3)
```

Thank you

Comment: Split x-axis according to what?

Comment: The problem is one of the parameters used for plotting is 310 while the other are around 50. So if I can clip/split the y-axis from 100 to 300, I can have a nice graph in place.

Comment: That is a hint and not an answer.

Comment: That's why it is a comment, not an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
df <- data.frame(
  Name=c("PRIM2", "NBPF20", "NBPF1", "CD24", "SEC22B", "ZNF718"),
  Freq=c(310, 45, 12, 11, 7, 7)
  )

library("plotrix")
gap.barplot(df$Freq, c(50,300), df$Name)
```

http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/plotrix/docs/gap.barplot

Comment: Thanks. looks like a cool package.